# Using List data in html pages hosted in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, list, office-365, html

I have hosted my html pages using sharepoint designer into my sharepoint online *Site pages*.

Now can I pull these list data inside this html pages in a formatted manner wherein design of list view is formatted according to my html page design.

For example, lets say I wanted to show the list data as *tabs* because that suits my html content.

Please Suggest any approach.

Comment: Please reply anyone

Comment: bumping for a reply since its urgent !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!